# Do your conversation options with Zelda the first time you meet her matter?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

The first time you meet Zelda, she asks you what you think of her outfit, with three choices.

Does your choice here have any lasting effect in the game?

Comment: I would be surprised if it did - that would be new for Zelda games. Mind you, I haven't gotten to play the game yet, so I could be wrong. :)

Comment: I'm quite far in the game already but I seriously doubt anything you say impacts the story at all. I got my sister to play where she chooses all the other options that I chose. Nothing is different as far as we could tell except for the initial reaction of the choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried all three reactions for multiple areas where you get to choose what to say - the only difference really is that the person you are speaking to will react to what you say in their next statement, but the game proceeds the same way no matter what you say.